# Has this OpenSSL bug been fixed? (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, openssl

https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20140605.txt

I need the fixes for the issues in this security advisory, for running cryptocurrency wallets.

(See https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/bitcoin-core-0-9-2-released-fixes-yet-another-openssl-vulnerability/ for more info)

But here's what I get when I check the OpenSSL version I have installed:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Apparently fixes are backported?  But the date that library shows gives me significant worries.  How can I be sure that these fixes were backported to the version of OpenSSL I have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find if issues are fixed are to search for the individual CVE numbers (which are in the notice there that went out) in the Security Team [CVE Tracker](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/).  This indicates whether specific CVEs have been fixed in Ubuntu or not, or whether the CVE even affects Ubuntu.

With regards to the notice you linked, **all the CVEs referenced in it are already fixed in Ubuntu's OpenSSL pacakges**.

> Obligatory link dump of Ubuntu Security Team CVE tracker data for some
>   of the CVEs in the OpenSSL notice:
>
> - CVE-2014-0224 (from that notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0224.html)
> - CVE-2014-0221 (from the notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0221.html)
> - CVE-2014-0195 (from the notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0195.html)
> - CVE-2014-0198 (from the notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0198.html)
> - CVE-2010-5298 (from the notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2010/CVE-2010-5298.html)
> - CVE-2014-3470 (from the notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-3470.html)
> - CVE-2014-0076 (from the notification): Fix Released (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0076.html)

---

***A note about OpenSSL Package Revision Numbers and the `openssl version` output***

*The packages for OpenSSL in Ubuntu are, for the most part, version locked to a specific version of OpenSSL in each Ubuntu release*.  That is to say, for Trusty, the core OpenSSL version is OpenSSL 1.0.1f, from January 2014.  This is only the *core* library versions, it does not take into account patches applied to it, etc.

*The way to determine whether the package has been updated with patches, etc. is via the Debian package revision number and corresponding changelog entries*.  The version of the OpenSSL package and corresponding libraries in Ubuntu Trusty is currently as of this post:

```
 openssl | 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2    | trusty           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 openssl | 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 | trusty-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 openssl | 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 | trusty-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
```

Looking at the second column, we see that the latest version available for OpenSSL is `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21`, which means it has had multiple revisions since the initial Trusty release (which had `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2`).

The package build rules for OpenSSL's package do not use the Debian string in the version data.  It uses only the OpenSSL original version string, `1.0.1f`.  This is why `openssl version` is misleading, and for pre-packaged versions of OpenSSL, you rely on the changelogs for the package, the Ubuntu security tracker, and the version string on the *package* rather than the `version` command in the packaged software (for OpenSSL, at least).

Comment: Hmm... but my Open SSL package is apparently from 6th Jan 2014, so how could they fix issues from later (June etc.) in 2014?

Comment: And they are fixed in packages with names like 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 according to those links, but I just have 1.0.1f according to 'openssl version'.

Comment: `$ apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
`

I guess it's OK?

Comment: @GreenMo The build string is version locked/fixed.  That's the original build of OpenSSL included, the version string changes by the -`ubuntuX.Y` prefix to indicate package changes that didn't include a full code version bump.  Do not rely solely on `openssl version` when using the prepackaged OpenSSL, rely on that version string plus the installed Ubuntu package revision number.

Comment: @GreenMo I've detailed the version string stuff more in the answer.